# tryptophan overload (or, simply python class initialization not working)

Tags: python

Python 3.4

So maybe it's the turkey digesting, or maybe it's my lack of python wizardry, but my simplistic idea for initializing instances of a class with several members all set to None doesn't seem to be working. To wit:

dataA.txt

```
# layername   purpose    stmLay  stmDat
topside       copper     3       5
levelA        trace5     6       8
```

shouldWork.py

```
#!C:/Python34

import sys
import re

class LayerDataInn:
 def __init__( self, layername, purpose, stmLay, stmDat):
   self.layername = layername
   self.purpose   = purpose
   self.stmLay    = stmLay
   self.stmDat    = stmDat
 def __init__( self, list_data):
   self.layername = list_data[0]
   self.purpose   = list_data[1]
   self.stmLay    = list_data[2]
   self.stmDat    = list_data[3]
 def display( self):
   print("layername"
         " purpose:",  self.purpose, \
         " stmLay:",   self.stmLay, \
         " stmDat:",   self.stmDat )
 def toList( self):
   return [ self.layername, \
            self.purpose, \
            self.stmLay, \
            self.stmDat ]

class LayerDataOut:
 def __init__( self, layername, purpose, stmLay, stmDat, maskColor):
   self.layername = layername
   self.purpose   = purpose
   self.stmLay    = stmLay
   self.stmDat    = stmDat
   self.maskColor = maskColor
 def __init__( self, list_data):
   self.layername = list_data[0]
   self.purpose   = list_data[1]
   self.stmLay    = list_data[2]
   self.stmDat    = list_data[3]
   self.maskColor = list_data[4]
 def display( self):
   print("layername"
         " purpose:",   self.purpose, \
         " stmLay:",    self.stmLay, \
         " stmDat:",    self.stmDat, \
         " maskColor:", self.maskColor )
 def toList( self):
   return [ self.layername, \
            self.purpose, \
            self.stmLay, \
            self.stmDat, \
            self.maskColor ]

class LayerDataOutOut( object):
 def __init__( self):
   self.layername = None
   self.purpose   = None
   self.stmLay    = None
   self.stmDat    = None
   self.maskColor = None
 def insert( self, *args):
   if( len( args) == 2):
     self.layername = list_data[0]
     self.purpose   = list_data[1]
     self.stmLay    = list_data[2]
     self.stmDat    = list_data[3]
     self.maskColor = list_data[4]
   if( len( args) == 6):
     self.layername = layername
     self.purpose   = purpose
     self.stmLay    = stmLay
     self.stmDat    = stmDat
     self.maskColor = maskColor
 def display( self):
   print("layername",   self.layername, \
         " purpose:",   self.purpose, \
         " stmLay:",    self.stmLay, \
         " stmDat:",    self.stmDat, \
         " maskColor:", self.maskColor )
 def toList( self):
   return [ self.layername, \
            self.purpose, \
            self.stmLay, \
            self.stmDat, \
            self.maskColor ]

# read the file
list_layerInn = []
fn_layerInn = "dataA.txt"
with open( fn_layerInn) as fp_layerInn:
 for line in fp_layerInn:
   list_layerInn.append( LayerDataInn( line.split()))

# list out the file
for objLayerInn in list_layerInn:
 objLayerInn.display()

list_layerOut = []
for objLayerInn in list_layerInn:
 list_objLayerInn = objLayerInn.toList()
 list_objLayerInn.append("woohoo")
 list_layerOut.append( LayerDataOut( list_objLayerInn))

# list out the file
for objLayerOut in list_layerOut:
 objLayerOut.display()

list_layerOutOut = []
for objLayerInn in list_layerInn:
 objLayerOutOut = LayerDataOutOut()
 setattr( objLayerOutOut, layername, getattr( objLayerInn, layername))  # <-- dies here
 setattr( objLayerOutOut, purpose,   getattr( objLayerInn, purpose))
 setattr( objLayerOutOut, stmLay,    getattr( objLayerInn, stmLay))
 setattr( objLayerOutOut, stmDat,    getattr( objLayerInn, stmDat))
 setattr( objLayerOutOut, maskColor, "wheeee" )
 list_layerOutOut.append( objLayerOutOut)

# list out the file
for objLayerOutOut in list_layerOutOut:
 objLayerOutOut.display()
```

I would expect that LayerDataOutOut's **init** would add the members with values of None , to be promptly updated with the setattr 's.

Overall goal here is to be able to instantiate an instance of a class with all members accounted for and set to None with just a simple call to the class with no arguments, like Java or C++

TIA,

Still-learning Steve

Comment: You re-defined `__init__`?  Multiple declarations of the same function name doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this line:

```
setattr( objLayerOutOut, layername, getattr( objLayerInn, layername))
```

This is the error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "shouldWork.py", line 109, in <module>
    setattr( objLayerOutOut, layername, getattr( objLayerInn, layername))
 dies here
NameError: name 'layername' is not defined
```

The reason you're receiving this error is because you're telling Python to use something called `layername`, which Python assumes is a variable name. However, you never created a variable called layername, so Python gets confused and crashes!

You probably meant to use a string instead:

```
setattr( objLayerOutOut, 'layername', getattr( objLayerInn, 'layername'))
```

This isn't a Python-specific thing -- the same thing would have happened in Java/C++. If you want to dynamically access the value of something at runtime, you typically need to provide the field name as a string.

Or better yet, dispense with `setattr` and `getattr`, and just directly set the field, just like Java:

```
objLayerOutOut.layername = objLayerInn.layername
```

Both approaches fixes your code.

---

As a side note, your code isn't 100% Pythonic. Here are some things I noted:

1. Unfortunately, Python doesn't support method overloading. If you declare two `__init__` methods, then the first one is overwritten by the second one. Instead, you'll typically use either default parameters, or the `*` or `**` argument unpacking operators. For example:

   ```
   def foo(a, b, c, d=None):
       print(a, b, c, d)

   foo(1, 2, 3)

   my_list = [5, 6, 7]
   foo(*my_list, d = 42)
   ```
2. In Python, each line is indented by exactly 4 spaces, by convention.
3. As I noted above, there's no need to use `setattr` and `getattr` -- instead, just directly set the field. We mainly use `setattr` or `getattr` when the name of the field/method we want to access are known only at runtime -- they're essentially metaprogramming tools.

Comment: as you've no doubt surmised I'm a python noob and its similarities and peculiarities to Java and Perl are causing my head to spin somewhat. I will try your suggestions. Thanks for your quick responses, folks.

Answer (score 1):

```
setattr( objLayerOutOut, layername, getattr( objLayerInn, layername))
```

`layername` is an attribute on `objLayerOutOut` and on `objLayerInn`, not a variable whose contents represent the name of the attribute you want to set. Use dot notation!

```
objLayerOutOut.layername = objLayerInn.layername
```

Same with the rest of them.